# Why is this Calculation not giving me a result

Tags: filemaker

I created an ExecuteSQL Calculation:

```
ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT BaseRent FROM obj_Unit_CurrentRenter_RentAmount WHERE RenterUnitID = ? AND CurRent  = 1" ; "," ; ""; RenterUnitID)
```

I've verified that is works when I take out the `AND CurRent = 1` clause. However, with that part in it, the calculation returns a ?.

CurRent is a Number field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your field name `CurRent` collides with the reserved word `CURRENT`.

Change your formula to:

```
ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT BaseRent FROM obj_Unit_CurrentRenter_RentAmount WHERE RenterUnitID = ? AND \"CurRent\"  = 1" ; "," ; ""; RenterUnitID)
```

Comment: I am away from my application currently but will test and provide feedback asap. I suspect you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: That was it! You were right.

Comment: You may want to consider using a custom function to quote all your field references. This will also protect your calculation against breaking when you rename a field.